# Clone azure app service from one subscription to another under the same tenant

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are trying to clone or restore AppServices from a stable environment in Azure while provisioning new environments.
The stable environment is in one Subscription but the new environments to be created are in another subscription. Both subscriptions are in the same tenant.
Ideally I would like to clone the AppServices from the stable envs when provisioning new environments instead of back/restore.
Is there any way through ARM templates or Powershell to clone an AppService under one subscription to
another subscription under the same Tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could do it with ARM templates:

1. Export template from the web app under your source subscription and deploy it to another subscription.
   [image]

---

2. Here is an official tutorial about [Move to different subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription?toc=/azure/app-service/toc.json#checklist-before-moving-resources) under one tenant. You could clone your web app and move one of them to another subscription.
   [image]

---

3. You could [backup your website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup#how-backups-are-stored) content, download from storage account, and deploy to another subscription.

---